# Oracle failover and SCN number

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got 2 Oracle servers in the failover solution. I also have a PL/SQL procedure that uses SCN numbers.

If, during the execution of this procedure, one server fails and processing is switched to the second server, does it mean that SCN number will be the same on the second server?

Answer (score 1):

If your  failover solution is an Oracle RAC 
and technically you are using multiple oracle instances with a singe data base, then:
Since SCN (system change number) is a data base concept and not an oracle instance concept
then 
during the execution of this procedure,when one server fails and processing is switched to the second server the SCN will be the same 
BUT
as a fact

> The database ALWAYS has transactions going on, ALWAYS.  SMON and many other background 
>   processes are always doing work, the database (unless it is opened read only) is always 
>   doing transactions.

so the SCN is allways changeing for oracles internal actions 
**you can not relay on SCN to be not changed during instance swiching process**

take a look at this:
[SCN By Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:48052838748707)